# Mysql NOT IN clause query does't return what I want

Tags: mysql, sql, notin

I Think I do not understand something but i have a very strange result with not in.

I have this kind of tables

TABLE membres

```
idMembre
1
2
...
```

Table membres_has_domaines

```
idMembre  idDomaine
1         10
1         11
1         40
2         10
2         13
2         20
3         40
3         22
```

i run this query

```
select m.idMembre from membres m 
inner join membres_has_domaines md on m.idMembre=md.idMembre 
where md.idDomaine not in (40) 
group by m.idMembre
```

and the result retuns me

```
idMembre
1
2
3
```

the question is... why user 1 and 3 is in this result ?

thanks a lot for your help

EDIT : 
after first answer, i understand the problem...
in reality my request is many more complex. I'm working on a full dynamic filter system generated by a HTML form where you choose your parameters...
requests looks like that. here i want members with domain matching (1,2) excluding members with domain 27 and having country in (64, 4, 24)

```
select m.idMembre,  memberName, 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct d.domaineName SEPARATOR ", ") as domaines , 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct a.zipAdresse SEPARATOR ", ") as zips, 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct p.countryName SEPARATOR ", ") as countryNames 
from membres
 m left join titres t on m.idTitre=t.idTitre 
left join civilites c on m.idCivilite=c.idCivilite 
left join adresses a on a.idMembre=m.idMembre left 
join pays p on a.idCountry =p.idCountry 
left join emails e on e.idMembre=m.idMembre 
left join membres_has_domaines md on md.idMembre=m.idMembre 
left join domaines d on md.idDomaine=d.idDomaine 
where 1=1 and md.idDomaine in (1, 2) 
and md.idDomaine not like '27' 
and a.idCountry in (64, 4, 24) 
group by m.idMembre
```

note ... this query don't do the job .. for the same reason of my original simplified example.

i don't know if i can do that without using having clause or subqueries ... it's quite complex. I think, the subqueries are the only way ? what do you think ? ...

Comment: Because you have records for all three users with entries different from 40 you can see it, if you use `Select * ` without ´` Group by`

Comment: Because rows exists where `idMembre in (1, 3)` and `idDomaine not in (40)`. You are probably looking for `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you have many records for each member, and when at least one of the records matches your `not in` condition, it will appear in the result set.

One approach is to find all the members which do have the offending record, and then return the complement set:

```
SELECT 
    m.idMembre 
FROM 
    membres_has_domaines m
WHERE
    m.idMembre NOT IN (
        SELECT idMembre 
        FROM membres_has_domaines 
        WHERE idDomaine = 40
    );
```

Comment: yes i think it could be the solution ... but if possible i would like to avoid generating subqueries ... because I'm on a full dynamic system and this is realy complex... for example i can have many params using the same linked tabes asked (see my original post update, and example).

Comment: again .. thank you. After burning my brain ... I've made modifications to my script to work like that ;) It seems it work now... but I must test many cases for ferifications. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

They are in the result because your data has rows that match the `not in` condition.

If you want users that do not have "40" at all, then you need to consider all the rows as a group.  Hence, think `group by` . . . along with a condition:

```
select md.idMembre
from membres_has_domaines md
where md.idDomaine not in (40) 
group by md.idMembre 
having sum( md.idDomaine in (40) ) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows for each member that match the condition.  The `= 0` says that no rows exist for the *member*.

Note that I removed the join to `membres`.  Given your sample data and query, it is not needed for the query.  If you want other columns, then it should be part of the query.

Comment: Hello. thank you for your answer... I must think about how to implement that in my system. I've made a full dynamic filter system automatically generated by a form ... and in reality there are many more parameters that can be requested...
The real example is I want to find members with domain in (1,2,3) excluding thoes who have domains in (4,5) ...

Comment: after tests. having will only work if i include the domain 40 in my where clause ... whiwh is not the case IRL for me ... :'(

Comment: @J.Doe . . . You should not edit your post, which invalidates that answers of people trying to help you.  You should ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you also have records as:

```
idMembre  idDomaine
1         10
1         11
3         22
```

So before group by the statement you will have next result:

```
 idMembre  idDomaine
 1         10
 1         11
 2         10
 2         13
 2         20
 3         22
```